# Bash: How to use functions with parameters with find and ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, find

I'm trying to search for files of a specific type on a remote ssh client, and want to call a function with the filename passed as a function parameter:

```
out=$(ssh operator@$IP << EOF
    check_cert_date () {
        echo "checking" $1
    }
    $(typeset -f)
    find /opt -iname *.der -o -iname *.pem  -exec bash -c 'for arg; do check_cert_date "$arg"; done' - {} \;
EOF
)
```

Files are found, but the filename itself is not passed to check_cert_date(), i.e. $1 is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for quoting with 'Here Documents'. Use `<< "EOF"`.

Also, `find` needs parens for your action to apply to both `*.der` and `*.pem` files:

```sh
find /opt \( -iname *.der -o -iname *.pem \) -print | while read -r file; do check_cert_date "$file"; done
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this but still the same issue - just get "checking" printed for all the files found - i.e. nothing for $1.

Comment: When you try the `find` without the `| while…`, do you get results?

Comment: Oh, quoting issue. Replace `<< EOF` with `<< "EOF"`.